# How to hide content in jinja that is displaying on page before execution?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, jinja2

I'm using Flask and trying to create a form that user will fill and when user will hit on submit then the output render on the same page but I'm facing a problem that content of jinja is also displayed before execution in the following way.

[image]

Is there any possible way to hide those content or any other efficient method to render the content on the same page ?

Comment: Please also include the relevant portion of the jinja2 template

Comment: You can wrap it in an if statement in jinja like this. {% if freq %} {{ freq }} {% endif %} but it would help if you add your template here.